# Is there a way to prevent the compiler to mess with inline assembly

Tags: c, arm, inline-assembly

So I have this piece of "dumb" mixed C code and ARM assembly

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    register int val asm("r0");
    register volatile int dummy asm("r2");
    register int res asm("r3");
    val = atoi(argv[1]);
    res = 0xfffffff;
    dummy = 0xffffffff;
    asm volatile(
         "cmp   r0,    #0   \n"
         "beq   edest       \n" 
         "movs  r2,    #0   \n"
         "b     fdest       \n"
 "edest : movs  r2,    #2   \n"
 "fdest : add   r3,    r2   \n"
     : 
     : 
     : "r0", "r2", "r3", "cc"
     );

    return res;
}
```

And I can't find a way to prevent the compiler to mess with it.
What I mean when I say "messing with it" :
- using any other registers.
- interleaving instructions generated from the compilation of the C code with ones from the inline assembly (with the jump targets resolved obviously).

Basically, I want to have this exact sequence of instructions somewhere in the binary.
I am cross compiling with gcc by the way, at O0.

Any hints of what I could be doing wrong?

Edit :
Here is the resulting assembly for the main fonction :

```
00008244 <main>:
    8244:   4800        ldr r0, [pc, #0]    ; (8248 <main+0x4>)
    8246:   e92d b004   stmdb   sp!, {r2, ip, sp, pc}
    824a:   e28d        b.n 8768 <__call_exitprocs+0x20>
    824c:   d008        beq.n   8260 <main+0x1c>
    824e:   e24d        b.n 86ec <strtol_l+0x28>
    8250:   0008        movs    r0, r1
    8252:   e50b        b.n 7c6c <_init-0x394>
    8254:   100c        asrs    r4, r1, #32
    8256:   e50b        b.n 7c70 <_init-0x390>
    8258:   300c        adds    r0, #12
    825a:   e51b        b.n 7c94 <_init-0x36c>
    825c:   3004        adds    r0, #4
    825e:   e283        b.n 8768 <__call_exitprocs+0x20>
    8260:   3000        adds    r0, #0
    8262:   e593        b.n 7d8c <_init-0x274>
    8264:   0003        movs    r3, r0
    8266:   e1a0        b.n 85aa <_strtol_l.isra.0+0x142>
    8268:   000d        movs    r5, r1
    826a:   eb00 3000   add.w   r0, r0, r0, lsl #12
    826e:   e1a0        b.n 85b2 <_strtol_l.isra.0+0x14a>
    8270:   0003        movs    r3, r0
    8272:   e1a0        b.n 85b6 <_strtol_l.isra.0+0x14e>
    8274:   320f        adds    r2, #15
    8276:   e3e0        b.n 8a3a <__retarget_lock_try_acquire_recursive+0x6>
    8278:   2000        movs    r0, #0
    827a:   e3e0        b.n 8a3e <__retarget_lock_release+0x2>
    827c:   0000        movs    r0, r0
    827e:   e350        b.n 8922 <__libc_fini_array+0x2e>
    8280:   0001        movs    r1, r0
    8282:   0a00        lsrs    r0, r0, #8
    8284:   2000        movs    r0, #0
    8286:   e3b0        b.n 89ea <__locale_ctype_ptr+0x16>
    8288:   0000        movs    r0, r0
    828a:   ea00 2002   and.w   r0, r0, r2, lsl #8

0000828c <edest>:
    828c:   2002        movs    r0, #2
    828e:   e3b0        b.n 89f2 <__locale_ctype_ptr+0x1e>

00008290 <fdest>:
    8290:   3002        adds    r0, #2
    8292:   e083        b.n 839c <memset+0x48>
    8294:   0003        movs    r3, r0
    8296:   e1a0        b.n 85da <_strtol_l.isra.0+0x172>
    8298:   d004        beq.n   82a4 <atoi>
    829a:   e24b        b.n 8734 <strtol+0x38>
    829c:   4800        ldr r0, [pc, #0]    ; (82a0 <fdest+0x10>)
    829e:   e8bd ff1e   ldmia.w sp!, {r1, r2, r3, r4, r8, r9, sl, fp, ip, sp, lr, pc}
    82a2:   e12f        b.n 8504 <_strtol_l.isra.0+0x9c>
```

It is so messed up, it is hard to match the original inline assembly with the final instructions

Comment: I'm more curious why you feel the need to use inline assembly to begin with? What is the problem you're trying to solve with it? What would the corresponding C code look like? And are you sure that the compiler won't be able to generate "better" code (especially with optimizations enabled)?

Comment: Can you add that messed up code you currently are getting?

Comment: Simply place the inline assembler in a function of its own?

Comment: As for a possible part of your problem, using `register` is only a *suggestion* for the compiler to place a value in a register. It might disregard it. I expect the register placement is also taken as a suggestion rather than something the compiler must obey.

Comment: What is getting messed up now?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's a GCC extension: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html#Local-Register-Variables

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am not looking for optimisation. I want to regenerate a binary code. I dont want to go too much into the details but I am trying to confirm some experimental results and It implies to generate an assembly with this exact sequence of instructions.

Comment: The disassembly is wrong. You are assembling ARM code and then disassembling Thumb code.

Comment: If you want to have certain values in certain registers for your assembly snippet to run, the correct way to do it is by defining input and output operands in [gcc extended asm syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).  Declaring variables `register`, as you've seen, isn't guaranteed to work reliably.

Comment: @user253751 - yup, I thought so.  GCC and clang definitely do *not* mess with inline asm other than to substitute operands into template parameters, if any.  (like filling in `r0` for `%1`).  And yes, as Nate says, `"+r"` / `"=r"` / `"r"` constraints are still necessary, with `asm int foo register("r1")` just forcing the choice of register.

Comment: @user253751 That was the issue. I forgot to add -mcpu=cortex-m4 and -mthumb to the compiling options.

Comment: @NateEldredge: The **only** effect of `register __asm__` that OP is using is to bind which register is used for an operand *when the variable is used as an operand to inline asm*. It does not make the variable "permanently live" in the register. So what OP has written is partly OK, but the input/output operands need to be bound rather than clobbered.

Comment: which compiler are we talking about here?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: The other showstopper with not using operands is that it wouldn't get treated as part of the dependency chain for the C vars, so constant-propagation or other optimizations could happen across the asm statement.  (And BTW, in practice GCC does "bind" the var to a reg, but clang doesn't.  But clobbers will defeat that, making the compiler save them elsewhere I think, entirely defeating this.)  Anyway, none of this will stop that exact sequence of instructions from appearing *somewhere* in the binary, just not in a useful place.

Comment: @Peter: Modern GCC documents that register asm is only bound as asm operands and that other usage was a legacy misfeature that can't be relied upon.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: If you look at code-gen, gcc is still pretty eager to move register vars into the specified register.  I didn't mean to imply it was anything you could rely on across all possible corner cases of surrounding code.  100% agreed that you can only rely on it for `"r"` in/out/both operands to Extended Asm statements, even though the implementation very often will have the var in that register at other times.

Answer (score 3):

> The disassembly is wrong. You are assembling ARM code and then disassembling Thumb code. – user253751 7 mins ago

Adding some compilation (-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb) options did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You have to constrain the asm inputs/outputs:

```
    asm volatile(
         "cmp   r0,    #0   \n"
         "beq   edest       \n" 
         "movs  r2,    #0   \n"
         "b     fdest       \n"
 "edest : movs  r2,    #2   \n"
 "fdest : add   r3,    r2   \n"
     : "+r"(val), "+r"(dummy), "+r"(res)
     : 
     : "cc"
     );
```

You could also remove the bindings to particular registers and instead use `%0`, `%1`, etc. in your asm to let the compiler assign them, but the above should work.

Comment: `dummy` constraint only needs to be output only (`=r`) .

Comment: Note that this doesn't answer the specific question at all; the exact sequence of instructions with still appear somewhere in the binary, just not in a useful place or with useful surrounding code!  (e.g. the compiler would save register vars into different registers, or memory, around an asm statement that clobbered the regs they were in.)  But +1 anyway for fixing the total showstopper bug in the OP's code.